# Insert Data into MySQL from Local File

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am trying to insert data into MySQL database from a local .txt file. MySQL command is this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Hotel/manager.txt' INTO TABLE MANAGER;
```

Text file looks very simple (just trying to test it at this point:

```
manager1    password    
manager2    password    
manager3    password
```

All field are separated by tab. 
When I run this command no data is inserted into a table. I get no errors but nothing is inserted. I tried moving .txt file to other locations with no luck. What is interesting, I never get a File Not Found error, no matter if .txt file is in the specified location or not.
Using macOS Catalina and XAMPP 7.1.32
Thank you in advance!

Comment: See http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/ for an example of how to do this. Additionally, have you read through https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html? It looks like the default field terminator is a tab, and line terminator is a newline, so those appear to be ok. What is your `MANAGER` table schema?

Comment: Thanks. Manager table schema are 3 fields with mID AUTO_INCREMENT. All of this used to work until I upgraded to the latest version of XAMPP a few days ago.

Comment: I suspect there may be a problem with some database setting after the upgrade as it is not even giving me File Not Found error no matter where I put the file or how I name it.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-column-list may be specifically what you're looking for because you're not currently providing the column list. There's a good chance it's failing because it's trying to insert `manager` into the first field, which is likely `mID`. Additionally, you're only trying to insert 2 fields into 3 columns.

Comment: Yes, 2 fields, 3 columns because the first column mID is auto incremented. It used to work. Anyway, I tried the link you provided - including all 3 values, using quotes and providing extra lines for field terminated by, enclosed by etc... no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding FIELDS TERMINATED and FIELDS TERMINATED, and also adding the names of the columns you want to populate:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE'/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Hotel/manager.txt' 
INTO TABLE MANAGER FIELDS TERMINATED by '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
set column_manager = @manager,
column_password = @password
```